# Selenium CSS Locator containing onclick on Firefox and IE

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I am using latest Selenium RC Python Client and Selenium RC Server. I am trying click a button on a webpage that has the following HTML Tag:

```
<input type="submit" id="b1" value="Button1 - Standard" onclick="javascript: alert('button1')">
```

The following Python Code clicks on the the above button using CSS Locator `xxx` 1st on Firefox, but not on IE.

On Firefox:

```
from selenium import selenium
s1 = selenium('myhost_ip_address', 4444, '*chrome', 'http://mypage_with_button.com')
print s1.is_element_present('css=input[value="Button1 - Standard"][type="submit"][id="b1"][onclick="javascript: alert(\'button1\')"]')
# Returns True
```

On IE8:

```
# NOTE: On IE, you might have to click on the notification 'To help protect your security... ActiveX controls that could....' and Allow Blocked Contents if needed
from selenium import selenium
s1 = selenium('myhost_ip_address', 4444, '*chrome', 'http://mypage_with_button.com')
print s1.is_element_present('css=input[value="Button1 - Standard"][type="submit"][id="b1"][onclick="javascript: alert(\'button1\')"]')
# Returns False
```

I am fully aware that I have unique ID for this css and I don't need attributes like type and onclick (I am just curious why this is happening).

To summarize, this post is particularly for a Selenium CSS locator having onclick as attribute, which works on Firefox but not on IE. Does anyone out there know why this is so??

Comment: Are you sure Firefox and IE8 are rendering the same html?  Maybe IE8 is doing some weird stuff and changing the markup.  Do you see the same markup if you inspect in both browsers?

Comment: Actually, for Firefox I can see the Source clearly and in detail using firebug, but not IE. Its not just `onclick`, even `onchange` and sometimes `style` attributes don't work... I am sure there are certain attributes that just cannot be used in CSS, but can be used by Xpath!!

Answer (score 0):

I have bad experience with locators regarding the onclick attribute. My conclusion is that the onclick attribute is transformed to JavaScript function object after rendering the HTML in browser so that matching via text pattern fail. No idea why it works in FF and in IE not. 
Maybe one browser uses native evaluation of CSS selectors ant the other the injected Sizzle engine.

Comment: I agree.  If you want to match on the contents of an onclick (or any other event) attribute, you should match on the minimum substring that is possible.

Comment: Thanks... Just FYI: If you provide xpath with onclick it works on both FF and IE. But for CSS, it does not work on IE